# use a global setting as an attribute argument

Tags: parameters, attributes

I want to specify an argument in an attribute, like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = GlobalSettings.GlobalVar)]
```

Where GlobalVar is a variable I defined only once (don't care where).

Using a configuration setting doesn't work anyhow, and I can't get it working with some static class either.

I get the error:
*An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array   creation expression of an attribute parameter type*

Maybe it's possible to write a custom wrapper around OutputCache, but that feels like a hack. Am I missing something here??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665187/how-to-set-dynamic-value-in-my-attribute/6665254#6665254

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that attribute values have to be determined at compile time - they're embedded in the assembly. That's why you have to use a constant expression (not just a global variable - truly a *constant*).

Comment: still it behaves as same? can't bind runtime values?

Comment: @ManirajSS: Attributes are compiled into the assembly, so no, they can't reflect anything at execution time. That doesn't stop whatever *uses* them from doing things at execution time of course - but that's only helpful if it's your code that is using them...

Comment: Thanks. So any suggestions/alternate options to bind values for cache expiry dynamic params of cache attribute?

Comment: @ManirajSS: Not in the comments of a question from over 15 years ago, for sure. Please ask a new question with appropriate details.