# C# Dynamic Attribute Arguments

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, browsable

Is there a way to do the following? I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392083/use-a-global-setting-as-an-attribute-argument) that the Attribute Arguments must be a constant expression, so how would I work around this?  If I dont want to load *some* properties into a datagridview using binding, whats the next best alternative?

```
  class TestObj
  {
     private bool isBrowsable = false;

     [Browsable(isBrowsable)]
     public string String1
     {
        get
        {
           return "Foo";
        }
     }
     [Browsable(isBrowsable)]
     public string String2
     {
        get
        {
           return "Baz";
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Do you want to decide this at compile-time or run-time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide dynamic custom type information at runtime by implementing the [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) interface - but this is quite a bit of work at not nearly as simple as decorating properties with attributes.

Comment: Do you have an quick example of this or a site that shows how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Here is an example that uses the interface to localize a grid. http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/propertygrid/article.php/c4795

Comment: given link broken

Answer (score 3):

For runtime, I think that you are probably looking at ICustomTypeDescriptor.  If it were a compile time decision, you could have used compiler directives:

```
 #define ISBROWSABLE
 #if ISBROWSABLE
 [your attribute]
 #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load value from some config file or database using approach similar to
[How to set dynamic value in my Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665187/how-to-set-dynamic-value-in-my-attribute/6665254#6665254) by passing class and property names, e.g.

[IsBrowsable("classname",  "propertyname")]

However it will be annoying to type as string names, that are obvious and somehow should be able to determined from reflection.
You can try to us IL Weaver tools, such as PostSharp or Fody.( I believe, that they capable to do such thinks, but don't have an example just now)☑