# Authorize attribute using a constant expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to set the Authorize for my controllers can do the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Approver")]
```

How ever the names of the roles are held in the database, and therefore I would like to try and do the following:

```
[Authorize(Roles = Settings.Instance.RoleEmployee)]
```

but I get the following error:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [SO - C# Dynamic Attribute Arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093466/c-dynamic-attribute-arguments)
- [SO - use a global setting as an attribute argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392083/use-a-global-setting-as-an-attribute-argument)

Comment: Both those links imply it's very difficult or impossible. it's relatively easy (5 total lines) to do this by creating your own authorization attribute (e.g. [AuthorizeApprover]) and using that instead. Not very scalable, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UniqueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{        
    public string Identifier { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {          
        // Get property value
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
        string identifierValue = properties.Find(this.Identifier,     true).GetValue(value).ToString();
    }
}
```

You will get value of any property  like this above

```
   [UniqueAttribute(Identifier = "Id")]
```

Answer (score 0):

If an "Employee" is a known role, then define this string constant in your application, and ensure the a role stored in the database can be mapped to this value when required.