# Why can't I use resources as ErrorMessage with DataAnnotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resources, data-annotations

Why can't I do like this?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", ErrorMessage = Resources.RegistrationModel.UsernameError)]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

What is the error message telling me?

> An attribute argument must be a
>   constant expression , typeof
>   expression or array creation
>   expression of an attribute parameter
>   type.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

When you are using the `ErrorMessage` property only constant strings or string literal can be assigned to it.

Use the `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName` instead to specity your resources.

```
[RegularExpression(
    "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", 
    ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.RegistrationModel),
    ErrorMessageResourceName= "UsernameError"
)]
```

Note that the resources must be **public** (can be set in the resource editor).

[image: Setting resource access to public]

Comment: What if the resource is in App_GlobalResources? You can't change the Access Modifier for globalresources. Would you be forced to move those resources elsewhere in order for them to work with DataAnnotations?

Comment: @JohanVauhkonen you can change the Build Action to `Embedded Resource` and Custom Tool to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`

Comment: This may work, but according to the ASP.NET CORE documentation here: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html#dataannotations-localization, we should be able to localize these DataAnnotation error messages without specifying resource name and type. Whatever I try, however, I do not mange to get this working. Can someone share some experience on that?

Answer (score 3):

Please see this link: <strike>http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-WCF-RIA-1469cbe2/sourcecode?fileId=19242&pathId=774666288</strike> (link broken, but left for attribution purposes)

```
public sealed partial class RegistrationData 
{ 
    [Key] 
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationErrorRequiredField", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorResources))] 
    [Display(Order = 0, Name = "UserNameLabel", ResourceType = typeof(RegistrationDataResources))] 
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationErrorInvalidUserName", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorResources))] 
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidationErrorBadUserNameLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ErrorResources))] 
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Comment: +1 for showing a complete list of attributes that use this pattern.  In particular, it's easy to miss that Display is different from the rest.  "Name" is the name in the resource file...

Answer (score 1):

Try [FluentModelMetaDataProvider](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/12/24/introducing-fluent-metadataprovider-for-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Managed to use resources for error messages in strongly typed fashion.

Looks like this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc.Extensibility;

namespace UI.Model
{
    public class StoreInputMetadata : ModelMetadataConfigurationBase<StoreInput>
    {
        public StoreInputMetadata()
        {
            Configure(m => m.Id)
                .Hide();
            Configure(model => model.Name)
                .Required(Resources.Whatever.StoreIsRequired)
                .MaximumLength(64, Resources.Whatever.StoreNameLengthSomething);
        }
    }
}
```

---

> What is the error message telling me?
>
> > An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.

It's already self explanatory. C# isn't dynamic language like Ruby where You can write classes that inherits random base class at runtime. :)

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392083/use-a-global-setting-as-an-attribute-argument/392096#392096) what Skeet says about this.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you cannot determine the value of the argument you are passing into the attribute at `runtime`, it must be at `compile time` so the value is embedded into the assembly.

The error message value needs to be a constant expression.

For information, attribute arguments can only be of types bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, double, string, System.Type, and enums.

Comment: Actually, David's answer directly addresses the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead look at the `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` properties of this attribute. They do allow the error message to be pulled from a resource.

Comment: What would the ResourceType be if fetched from the App_GlobalResources folder?

Comment: Resources.RegistrationModel, at a guess?

Answer (score 0):

We can now use nameof for strongly typed error messages:

```
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", 
  ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.RegistrationModel),
  ErrorMessageResourceName=nameof(Resources.RegistrationModel.UsernameError)
)]
```