# Using resources with error message in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, resources

I want to get error message from resources. When i tried codes below i take that error:"An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type" What can i do ?

```
public class UserLoginModel
{
     [Required(ErrorMessage =Resources.PageResources.enterYourEmail)]
     public String Email{ get; set; }

     [Required(ErrorMessage =Resources.PageResources.enterPassword)]
     public String Password { get; set; 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I use resources as ErrorMessage with DataAnnotations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688888/why-cant-i-use-resources-as-errormessage-with-dataannotations)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this

```
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),       
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "enterYourEmail")]
 public String Email{ get; set; }

 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),       
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "enterPassword")]
 public String Password { get; set;
```

Comment: I had to add ErrorMessage = null to make it work with asp.net mvc 5. Like:

[Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources.ModelStateErrors.Index),
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "passworddonotmatch", ErrorMessage = null)]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

Answer (score 3):

A similar approach but without the problem related by @Ali Baig about to have to add ErrorMessage = null to make it work.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Resources.Global_Errors.ReqName),
 ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global_Errors))]
```