# How can I make my own ErrorMessage in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a static method that returns a string that describes the error message in the chosen languages, but I can't make it work. I have searched for an answer, but only found a way to do it with: `[Display(Name = "Name")]` to my own: `[DisplayResource.DisplayName("InfoName")]`

Something like this, must be possible with this:

```
[StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = DisplayResource.DisplayError("ErrName"))]

[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = DisplayResource.DisplayError("ErrUseEMail"))]

[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = DisplayResource.DisplayError("ErrPswLength"))]

[Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = DisplayResource.DisplayError("ErrPswMatch"))]
```

and so on....

I have searched for an answer, but maybe I haven't used the right words to describe my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using resources with error message in mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940523/using-resources-with-error-message-in-mvc)

Comment: It's not exactly the same approach, but the idea is pretty similar.