# Validate login form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I wan't to validate a login form. I just wan't to check if the email field and password field are filled in. If not, an error message should display. I can't get it to work.

My actionresult Login:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string email, string password, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                User user = accountDal.GetAllUsers().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == email && x.Password == password);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
                    Response.Redirect(returnUrl, false);
                }
                return View();
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

So as you can see, I check if the ModelState is valid.

Here is my login view:

```
@model ProjectInvoice.ViewModels.LoginViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
}
```

And my ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

If I use a breakpoint at the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` it says it is true, while this is not the case. Am I missing something, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The parameters `email` and `password` are correct?

Comment: yes, the login part works, but if I leave the fields empty and click the button, the page just refreshes

Comment: thats not how you want to redirect in MVC. you want to say `return Redirect(redirectUrl);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have something like following:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel loginViewModel, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            User user = accountDal.GetAllUsers().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == loginViewModel.Email && x.Password == loginViewModel.Password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
                Response.Redirect(returnUrl, false);
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View(loginViewModel);
}
```

The reason why it is not working is `ModelState.IsValid` validates your model against the data annotation applied to the LoginViewModel class's members.

Comment: I see, this works fine! thank you! I must wait a few minutes before I can accept your answer

Comment: is it also possible to make a custom validation message?

Comment: @bbvanee Yes you can by `[Required(ErrorMessage="some meaningful message here")]`

Comment: and if I wan't to translate this message, can I call this message in my resources, like 'Email.ErrorMessage'?

Comment: @bbvanee Yes you can probably you would like to visit this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/17940523/1505865

Answer (score 3):

You need to post back your model so the properties of your model can be validated

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ....
```

Note also, when you return the view, you need to return the model

```
return View(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use data annotations. Like this:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This will invalidate you're model state. And then, in the contriller, you return it to the View using something liek this:

```
return View(model)
```

Comment: Yes I realized that after posting the answer. Sorry about that. But you have to return the model to the view in order for the validation message to be available.