# How to get a localized attribute error message with parameters?

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations

I use validation attributes and I want to localize my error messages. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2688965/4961688):

```
[RegularExpression(
    "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$", 
    ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(Resources.RegistrationModel),
    ErrorMessageResourceName= "UsernameError"
)]
```

You can even do it with a resource string like this:

```
"{0} is in an invalid format."
```

And it will fill in the property name. Almost what I want, however instead of the property name I want to pass a specific string like `"User name"` or `"Phone number"` (actually I want to get those strings from the resource file as well).

Is this possible? Or do I have to have a lot of very similar strings in my resource file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Display](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute.

Example

```
[Display(Name = "Description", ResourceType = typeof(Messages))]
public MessageModel Description { get; set; }
```

Sure, `Name` parameter should be named like string in resources.