# Using Data Annotations with Resources.Messages C#

Tags: c#, .net, validation, data-annotations

i'm a student and beginner developer.

I'm on a project on my workplace.. and I'm using Data Annotations for validation... but I need to use Resources.Messages to implement dynamic error messages. Here goes an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
[Required (ErrorMessage = (string.Format(Messages.MissingParameter, Messages.Ad)))]
    [Range(0, long.MaxValue)]
    public long? Ad { get; set; }
```

In this scenario, missing parameter is the follow string "The parameter {0} is required" and Messages.Ad is a string with the internacionalized field.

Soo, if I use Data Annotation, there's a few solutions, like using the ErrorResource... (like this RegularExpressions example -> [Why can't I use resources as ErrorMessage with DataAnnotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688888/why-cant-i-use-resources-as-errormessage-with-dataannotations))

But these don't contemplate the issue of passing strings that use parameters to deliver the final string (as illustrated on string.format)

So, my question is: How to use complex internationalization string's with data Annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You can't because you have to use specific values that are able to be used as attribute parameters.

From [MSDN - Attributes Tutorial C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx) :

Attribute parameters are restricted to constant values of the following types:

- Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
- string
- System.Type
- enums
- object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)
- One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types