# Dynamically change serialized datamember name in .NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am using .NET WebAPI to build a custom API.  What I am looking to do is dynamically change a properties datamember name at runtime.  I understand that I can override the name by using the DataMember(Name="whateverId")  but I want to be able to dynamically change it.

See my example below.  The class has an id and a name field.  Sometimes I may want it to appear as "eventId" and "name".  Other times I may want it to be "subEventId" and "name".

Any ideas how to do this dynamically.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "pair")]
public class idName
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public idName()
    {

    }

    public idName(int? id, string name, string serializeIdName = "id")
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I can create a new datamemberattribute in code but I don't know what to do with it next.

```
        var dma = new DataMemberAttribute();
        dma.Name = "whateverId";
```

Thanks!

Comment: The following post may provide some suggestions for your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665187/how-to-set-dynamic-value-in-my-attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use serialization callback, like so:

```
[DataContract]
public class IdName
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
```

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
private string EventId { get; set; }

[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
private string SubEventId { get; set; }

[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string Name { get; set; }

[OnSerializing]
void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
{
    bool isEvent = true;
    if (isEvent)
    {
        this.EventId = this.Id.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        this.SubEventId = this.Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How would this work if I wanted to make a call like this:   var oId = new idName(5,"test","nameToSerializeAs").  I really am looking to just pass a name into the constructor and have it serialize as that name.

Comment: Okay, passing the name is a new requirement. Your original post asks for ID to be serialized sometimes as EventID and other times as SubeventID and that should be taken care off by the code above.

Comment: Your post did help think of an alternate solution. Not exactly dynamic but better than having duplicate objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my less than ideal but improved approach.

```
public class idName
{

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? id { get; set; }

    #region Alternate id names

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? eventId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int? subEventId { get; set; }

    //as many other id's as needed.

    #endregion

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    public idName() { }

    public idName(int? id, string name, string displayIdName = "id")
    {
        this.name = name;

        PropertyInfo prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(displayIdName);
        if (prop == null)
            this.id = id;
        else
            prop.SetValue(this, id);

    }
}
```