# How to build a const string for a validation atribute in modelview?

Tags: c#, .net, string, constants

I want to build a const string with a default value from database.

So when I do such:

```
private const String nifInvalid = MensagensCacheManager.getMensagem(
        MensagensCacheManager.GetLanguage(), 
        "empresa.nif.invalid");
```

So I have the following error:

> 'nifInvalid' must be constant

I could use `static readonly` but i want to use it for a custom validation message such as:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(^[0-9]+$)|(\d{8})([-]?)([A-Z]{1})", ErrorMessage=nifInvalid)]
public String nif { set; get; }
```

How could i build a custom validation and set custom validation message?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [How to set dynamic value in my Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6665254/3970411)

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**. `const`s value should be specified during compile time.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx):

> Constant fields and locals aren't variables and may not be modified.
>   Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null
>   reference. Don’t create a constant to represent information that you
>   expect to change at any time.
>
> The type of a constant declaration specifies the type of the members
>   that the declaration introduces. The initializer of a constant local
>   or a constant field must be a constant expression that can be
>   implicitly converted to the target type. A constant expression is an
>   expression that can be fully evaluated at compile time. Therefore, the
>   only possible values for constants of reference types are string and a
>   null reference.

There is a workaround which Darin has mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36981418/3970411) but you should now [the difference between static readonly and const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/755685/3970411).

If you want to have attributes with dynamic values then you can use this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6665254/3970411).

Comment: To expand on this correct answer; a constant value is replaced at compile time with the constant value, so in no cases can it be derived at runtime, even if the value will not change during the exection of the program it cannot be permitted to change from the point of compilation onward - so deriving it from an external resource is not possible or desirable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a const in this case because fetching a value from a database by definition happens at runtime, so you cannot be talking about a *constant*. A constant is something that is known at compile time. In your case you could use `static readonly` field:

```
private static readonly string nifInvalid = MensagensCacheManager.getMensagem(MensagensCacheManager.GetLanguage(), "empresa.nif.invalid");
```

Comment: Sure i could, but i want to use this String for:
[RegularExpression(@"(^[0-9]+$)|(\d{8})([-]?)([A-Z]{1})", ErrorMessage=nifInvalid)]
public String nif {set; get;}

And for this it must be a const.
Any help?

Comment: Then why is this so important information not part of your question? You can't do that because by definition a constant value must be known at compile time. You will have to write your own custom attribute to achieve this effect. Is this for an ASP.NET MVC application or something else? Please provide the relevant information if you want your question to make sense. So now please go ahead and edit your question by providing the required context.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you intend to use it for, a const string cannot be calculated at runtime, it has to be a constant *literal* in the source code, or an expression only involving other const members.

Comment: Edited with all information